# Code Generation error while creating Api Controller in VS 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, controller

I am trying to create a Web API controller, but it somehow always throws the following error:

There was an error running the selected code generator:
The value -1 is outside the acceptable range of [02147483647]. Parameter name Value

I have removed the extra NuGet packages I added, like Cors, Owin, etc but it is still throwing that error

Comment: Exactly how are you trying to create the controller, and where does this error show? It sounds somehow like there is some error in a file behind that VS uses to help you create the controller (the created controller would be a .cs-file, you can create it manually if you want to and add controller definition inside yourself).

Answer (score 1):

I too got the same error while auto generating API controller code.

Since I was just messing around with a practice project, I just took the liberty to upgraded my project to the latest ASP.NET Core version along with the NuGet packages required by the code generating tool

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

After the updates The Code generation tool worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the Web Api via 'Web API Controller Class (v2.1).. this works for me..

Looks like an update problem with VS2019